# Неправильно сохраняет результат в файл

Tags: c

Идет сохранение результата в файл, но сохраняет не то что нужно. Исправьте ошибку.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

int main ()
{
    double a, b, d, x, s;
    FILE *fp;
    printf("\nVvedite znachenie a, b, d, x: ");
    scanf("%lf%lf%lf%lf",&a ,&b,&d,&x);

    if ( fp ) {  
        fp = fopen( "H.txt", "w" );      
        assert( fp != NULL );                     
        s = (a*a+b+cos(x))/(d*d*d+(a+d-b));
        printf("Otvet: \nK= %4.4lf",s);

       fprintf ( fp, "%d\n", s);
       fclose( fp );
    }

    getch();
}
```

Comment: "сохраняет не то что нужно" - полезным будет сказать, что нужно, и что сохраняется. Здесь не много охотников играть с Вами в игру "Угадайку".

Comment: сохраняет левые цифры.  а должен сохранять результат вычислений

Comment: "левые цифры" - это которые в числе с левой стороны, или "неправильные, неизвестно откуда взявшиеся"?

Comment: Проверка `if (fp)` до инициализации `fp = fopen(...)` не имеет смысла.

Answer (score 1):

У вас нарушен порядок предложений. Должно быть

```
    fp = fopen( "H.txt", "w" );      
    assert( fp != NULL );  
    if ( fp ) {  
    //...
```

Как уже было отмечено в комментариях, вы к тому же используете неправильный формат для вывода числа с плавающей запятой в файл

```
   printf("Otvet: \nK= %4.4lf",s);

   fprintf ( fp, "%d\n", s);
                 ^^^
```

Comment: Это, конечно, правильное замечание, но, думается мне, у ТС проблема в другом. Например, перепутаны градусы и радианы.

Comment: @Igor Про градусы и радианы в его вопросе ничего сказано не было. Что он там вычисляет, это только ему известно.

Comment: если что это градусы.. но вопрос не в том. вычисляет все правильно.. но в файл записывает не правильный ответ, а какие-то левые цифры..

Comment: исправил. не помогло.

Comment: @Roll, формат `%d` применяется для int, а для `double s` нужен формат `%f` (вообще `a, A, e, E, f, F, g, or G` (см. [man fprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fprintf)))

Comment: Функция `double cos(double value)` принимает аргумент в радианах.

Comment: @aleks.andr Это уже больше вопрос по математике, чем по программированию. Следует читать описание функций перед их использованием.:)

Answer (score 1):

Вот ещё ошибка:

```
double a, b, d, x, s;
/* ... */
fprintf ( fp, "%d\n", s );
```

Переменная `s` имеет тип `double`, а пишется как `int`. Измените формат `%d` на тот, что нужен в этом случае.

Comment: и из-за этого не правильно записывается ответ?

Comment: @Roll, в `printf()` вы выводите результат как `%4.4lf`. Ответьте на простой вопрос (не мне, а самому себе): "почему именно так, что означают эти символы?"